# How to solve Django send_mail schedule problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, email

I am using Pythonanywhere (PA) and like to use the PA's task scheduler (it runs every day and chacks if it is Wednesday or not) to send scheduled emails. I made a new file in my app folder called: `weeklyemailmm.py`. The email settings in the setting.py works with other emailing stuff on my site. What am I doing wrong?

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'xxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 'xxx'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxx'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I try to use the code below:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
import datetime
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(settings, DEBUG=True)


today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()

subject = 'New weekly email'
message = 'Hi there!'

if (weekday == 2):
    try:
        send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@gmail.com',
        ['to@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
        )

        print('It is Wednesday, email sent')
    except:
        print('It is not Wednesday')
else:
    print('Email does not sent')
```

On this way I always get `It is not Wednesday.`

If I delete the try-except part and outdent it says:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

If I delete the `settings.configure(settings, DEBUG=True)` that could be possibly wrong it say:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Traceback

```
    PSA/firm/weeklyemailmm.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ruszakmiklos/Documents/GitHub/MPSA/firm/weeklyemailmm.py", line 23, in <module>
    send_mail(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 52, in send_mail
    connection = connection or get_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 34, in get_connection
    klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 249, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.default_settings, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)...
```

And line 84 and 249 so on.

Comment: Could you please share you `settings.py` details ?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post.

Comment: Are the emails reaching the SMTP server you have configured? If so, do you see any errors in the SMTP logs on that end? Is your SMTP server open to connections over that host and post, with those creds, over TLS?

Django unfortunately has no logging out of the box for the default email backend. Perhaps to rule out the server and narrow the issue down further, you could try switching to the console backend and confirming that it works with that?

Comment: Share the entire traceback so we can see from where is this RecursionError coming.

Comment: I think the recursion issue is related to calling settings.configure with settings (the same object) as the argument.

Comment: Thank you guys, I added the long traceback.

Comment: If I change the `settings.configure(settings, DEBUG=True)` to
`settings.configure(DEBUG=True)` it doesn't shows the traceback but the email does not sent.

Comment: The very strange thing for me if I add the code to the views.py and run it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using **EmailMessage** :

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage


today = datetime.date.today()
weekday = today.weekday()

subject = 'New weekly email'
message = 'Hi there!'

if (weekday == 2):
    try:
        msg = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'from@gmail.com',
    ['to@gmail.com'])
        msg.send()
    
        print('It is Wednesday, email sent')
    except:
        print('It is not Wednesday')
else:
    print('Email does not sent')
```